# remove only hidden class elements instead of all of them

Tags: jquery, css

```
.slidercard:nth-of-type(1){
    display:none;
}
.slidercard:nth-of-type(2){
    display:none;
}
```

**js**

```
var b = $('.slidercard').length;
console.log(b);  // result: 14 - that's ok

$('.slidercard').each(function(){
     if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});

var b = $('.slidercard').length;
console.log(b);  // result: 0
```

But result should be `12` because only two of `slidercard` are `display:none`.

Also, on screen I see - all `.slidecard` are removed, instead of only two.

Comment: show your HTML sctructure

Comment: @TemaniAfif, `<div class='slidercard'>...</div>` - 14x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that while you are iterating with jQuery's each method you are **removing** the sildecard items. With each iteration you are making the next items 1st and 2nd - and therefore hidden by your CSS. The first item will always be hidden and therefore removed, resulting in all items being removed.
A better approach using jQuery's selector would be:

`$('.slidercard:hidden').remove();`

Or to maintain your logical flow, an alternative could be:

```
var hiddenArr = [];
$('.slidercard').each(function(){
    if ($(this).css("display") == "none") {
        hiddenArr.push($(this));
    }
});
hiddenArr.forEach((element) => {element.remove();});
```

Comment: was writing the same thing :) by the way only the 1st is considered ... as we are always having the first on each iteration ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.slidercard').find(':hidden').each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

each will pass on element child's that hidden

Comment: this also works. do you know why my code doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

As `@AlonGadot` mentioned the problem with your code is that while you are iterating with jQuery's each method you are removing the sildecard item.

So I give you an alternative answer, you can hide the elements via jquery with `eq()` method, so you can reduce a lot the code than the otherwise it´s so longer script for just removing hidden elements:

```js
var b = $('.slidercard').length;
console.log(b);  // result: 14 - that's ok

$(".slidercard").eq(0).hide().eq(1).hide()
$(".slidercard:hidden").remove()
    
b = $('.slidercard').length;
console.log(b);  // result: 0
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 1</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 2</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 3</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 4</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 5</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 6</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 7</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 8</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 9</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 10</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 11</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 12</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 13</div>
<div class="slidercard">Paragraph 14</div>
</body>
```